# Seaborn title error - AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_title

Tags: python, seaborn

I created a lineplot graph to begin with using the following code:

```
plot = sns.lineplot(data=tips,
             x="sex",
             y="tip",
             ci=50,
             hue="day",
             palette="Accent")
plot.set_title("Value of Tips Given to Waiters, by Days of the Week and Sex", fontsize=24, pad=30, fontdict={"weight": "bold"})
plot.legend("")
```

I have realised that its actually a catplot chart that I need so I amended the code to the following:

```
plot = sns.catplot (data=tips,
             x="day",
             y="tip",
             kind='bar',
             ci=50,
             hue="sex",
             palette="Accent")
plot.set_title("Value of Tips Given to Waiters, by Days of the Week and Sex", fontsize=24, pad=30, fontdict={"weight": "bold"})
plot.legend("")
```

However I am getting the following error message with the title: 'AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_title''.

Why is my title not working for the catplot chart?

Comment: Does this answer your question? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920341/python-seaborn-facetgrid-change-titles>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call catplot, it returns a FacetGrid object, so to change the the title and remove legend, you have to use the `legend=` option inside the function, and also use `plot.fig.suptitle()` :

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
plot = sns.catplot (data=tips,
             x="day",
             y="tip",
             kind='bar',
             ci=50,
             hue="sex",
             palette="Accent", legend=False)

plot.fig.suptitle("Value of Tips Given to Waiters, by Days of the Week and Sex",
                  fontsize=24, fontdict={"weight": "bold"})
```

[image]

Comment: great thanks, how did you get access to the data set I am using though ;) ?!

Comment: it's part of seaborn package? ```tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")```

Comment: Using `plot.fig` is deprecated in favour of `plot.figure` as of v0.11.2 (August 2021). See the [corresponding PR](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/2639).

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @StupidWolf, but with additional adjustment for title position:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
plot = sns.catplot (data=tips,
             x="day",
             y="tip",
             kind='bar',
             ci=50,
             hue="sex",
             palette="Accent", legend=False);
plot.figure.subplots_adjust(top=0.8);
plot.figure.suptitle(
    "Value of Tips Given to Waiters, by Days of the Week and Sex",
    fontsize=24,
    fontdict={"weight": "bold"}
);
```